# anchor tag not visible on row hover

Tags: asp.net, html, css

```
<div class="container">
<div class="name">Jack</div>
<a href="#" class="modify">Edit</a>
</div>

.container .modify {display:none}
.container:hover .modify, .container:focus .modify{display:block}
```

When user press tab key focus is on div container, edit link is displayed. But if user press tab again instead of focusing on edit link edit is hidden again. I want if focus is on div and user presses tab focus should go on Edit link.

please follow http://jsfiddle.net/lakshya85chd/8Y74X/

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate what you mean? I'm not aware of being able to have a focus on a `<div>`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lakshya85chd/8Y74X/

Comment: I've had a play, and I can see what you mean, but I haven't a clue how to get it work, sorry. Good luck finding a solution

Comment: Found solution checkout the following link
http://jsfiddle.net/lakshya85chd/MFmMD/

Comment: Found solution checkout the following link
http://jsfiddle.net/lakshya85chd/MFmMD/

Answer (score 1):

if it is display none you cant hover over it so use visibility hidden

```
.container .modify {visibility:hidden;}
.container .modify:hover, .container .modify:focus{visibility:visible;}
```

Comment: Hi satya..thnx for reply.. but the solution u provided didnt work.. i am trying to update the link in jsfiddle

Comment: Sorry, actually i didn't read your question properly actually you can't give :hover,:focus in between selector they should be applied to the end class like i gave above

Comment: Found solution checkout the following link
http://jsfiddle.net/lakshya85chd/MFmMD/